# How to consume from beanstalk tube

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, beanstalkd, beanstalkc

I am using beanstalk to put messages in the tube and i want to consume it from the new EC2 instance that i will launch at runtime. I am able to put message in the tube but i am not able to consume it by any means.

I performed the below steps to test:

file: producer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import greenstalk
import json
import sys

beanstalkTube = 'tube-name'
beanstalkHost = 'host'
beanstalkPort = 11301

client = greenstalk.Client((beanstalkHost, beanstalkPort))
client.use(beanstalkTube)

client.put('message 1')
```

file: consumer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import greenstalk
import json
import sys

beanstalkTube = 'tube-name'
beanstalkHost = 'host'
beanstalkPort = 11301

client = greenstalk.Client((beanstalkHost, beanstalkPort))
client.use(beanstalkTube)


job = client.reserve()

print("job_id:"+job.id)
print("job_body:"+job.body)
```

One more thing i want to know is how should i use the beanstalk to pass message to the newly created EC2 spot instance via shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will `use` a tube to put in a message.
Reading from the tube(s), you `watch` one (or more) tubes and the server will return a message when you call `reserve` to get one

> Jobs will only be reserved from tubes on the watch list, which initially contains a single tube, *default*. You can add tubes to the watch list with `watch` and remove them with `ignore`. For convenience, it can be set with the `watch` argument when creating a Client. https://greenstalk.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#consuming-jobs